# FilesMatch htaccess syntax pain for apache 2.4

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

someone please tell me why this doesn't work in .htaccess?

```
#grant access if word-processing format
<FilesMatch "\.([Pp][Dd][Ff]|[Dd][Oo][Cc][Xx]?|[Rr][Tt][Ff]|[Oo][Dd][Tt]|[Tt][Xx][Tt]|[Ww][Pp][Dd])$">
        Require all granted
</FilesMatch>

#deny access for double file extensions
<FilesMatch ".*\.([^.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

If I look at this any longer I'll have pulled all my hair out!

So it's not blocking e.g ' extensions.conf' from being uploaded.. the regex is right so it must be the syntax for Apache 2.4 htaccess.. restrictions in the htaccess above this block are being respected (e.g. no indexing) so the file is being parsed.  Does this syntax look correct?

*edited to actually ask a question

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want this to do. We can't tell if the regex is right if you don't tell us what you expect it to match. Also explain how you're checking whether it works, and which of the two doesn't work. Both? Only one? Does a simple pattern like `<FilesMatch "\.doc$">` work as you expect?

Comment: dots in filenames aren't used only for extensions.  iI's not at all uncommon to use a `.` instead of a space in filenames with multiple words - e.g. `foo.bar.txt`.   BTW apache filesmatch uses pcre, so you can use case insensitive patterns like `\.(?i)(pdf|docx?|rtf|odt|txt|wpd)$`

Comment: thanks @cas, so looks like this works if I add it into apache2.conf, but even with Allow Override all, it is not working in .htaccess. I'm good with it working from within  the main 
config file though!